# When application is being submitted to Executor, memory size is configurable, how about num of cpu?

Tags: apache-spark

So by default, spark will reverse all the available resource on each node, and when a application being submitted to the master, master will claim a executor on each worker node.So executor memory is 512mb by default which is configurable, but for cpus, usually I see 1 core assigned for my application through the master UI. So 1 core for each application is by default as well? Do I need to configure spark.cores.max  property so that my application can have more cores? and if that's the case, let's say I have 4 core available on each worker node, and I set the system property for spark.cores.max.property to 4 before I create the sparkContext, then will all 4 cores being assigned to my app? and also, is that true that the number of cores being used for my application is base on the number of partitions I have for each work node?

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting to assign the number of cores per executor: `spark.executor.cores`.  Based on the number of executors you have per node, you set this accordingly to use all your resources.

Regarding `spark.cores.max`, this setting depends on your resource manager (Mesos, Yarn, Spark stand-alone mode), as stated by [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), and I don't think it's what you need to worry about setting:

> When running on a standalone deploy cluster or a Mesos cluster in
>   "coarse-grained" sharing mode, the maximum amount of CPU cores to
>   request for the application from across the cluster (not from each
>   machine). If not set, the default will be spark.deploy.defaultCores on
>   Spark's standalone cluster manager, or infinite (all available cores)
>   on Mesos.

Regarding your question about, "is that true that the number of cores being used for my application is base on the number of partitions I have for each work node", I'm not sure on this.. Maybe if your data is really small, then you won't max out cpu's.

Side note: if you're running Spark with `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true` (disabled by default according Spark documentation, but enabled by default on AWS EMR's Spark setup), then the number of executors will be set based on the resources requested and available. Thus for me, I determine how much memory my executor needs, and then divvy up resources accordingly.